# Cons of using compound components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple components:

```
const Sidebar = (props) => { ... }
const SidebarLink = (props) => { ... }
```

To avoid bloat in `import`s I want to do simple namespacing:

```
Sidebar.propTypes = propTypes
Sidebar.Link = SidebarLink
export default Sidebar
```

And use it like:

```
<Sidebar>
  <Sidebar.Link>...</Sidebar.Link>
  <Sidebar.Link>...</Sidebar.Link>
  <Sidebar.Link>...</Sidebar.Link>
</Sidebar>
```

**Question:**

Are there any cons for this approach? 
Can somethings go wrong? 
Is it fine as a whole?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I find it generally adds more complexity than they are worth, but this article discusses som potential upsides and drawbacks on using sub-components in React in more detail. [Article found here](http://jakewiesler.com/blog/compound-component-basics).

Answer (score 3):

I have used this approach quite often when I was earliest stage of learning React.

Here's how I did:

```
export const Sidebar = (props) => { ... }
export const SidebarLink = (props) => { ... }
```

And when we needed to use them:

```
import * as Sidebar from '...' // path to the exports
<Sidebar.Sidebar>
  <Sidebar.SidebarLink>...</Sidebar.Link>
  <Sidebar.SidebarLink>...</Sidebar.Link>
  <Sidebar.SidebarLink>...</Sidebar.Link>
</Sidebar.Sidebar>
```

But it looks a little uglier in your case. Here's what I'd have used this approach: (Just an example)

```
<Sidebar.ExportOne />
<Sidebar.ExportTwo />
<Sidebar.ExportThree />
```

When I used this approach exactly?

I used this approach whenever I need to use several components:

```
// ComponentOne.js
export const ComponentOne = () => {}


// ComponentTwo.js
export const ComponentTwo = () => {}


// ComponentThree.js
export const ComponentThree = () => {}

// ...

// ComponentIndex.js
export { ComponentOne } from 'ComponentOne'
export { ComponentTwo } from 'ComponentTwo'
// ...
```

And now using it in separate component. So, it's be better to import all rather than using import statement a huge number of lines:

```
import * as ComponentAll from 'ComponentIndex'
<ComponentAll.ComponentOne />
<ComponentAll.ComponentTwo />
...
```

---

But obviously, there's one big **con while using this approach**, this will impact on performance. Continue reading below to see it why:

You'll be importing all of the components even though, you'll not be using some component. For eg.:

```
// PlaceOne.js
<ComponentAll.ComponentOne />
<ComponentAll.ComponentThree />

// PlaceTwo.js
<ComponentAll.ComponentTwo />
<ComponentAll.ComponentFive />
```

So, you're importing all exported components in the `PlaceOne.js` and `PlaceTwo.js`.

To avoid this con, use import statement like:

```
import {
  ComponentOne,
  ComponentTwo,
  // ... import only required component
} from 'ComponentIndex'
// Now, you can simply use:
<ComponentOne />
<ComponentTwo />
```

This concludes that using `<ComponentOne />` rather than `<ComponentAll.ComponentOne />` is better approach. And also, we will not loose code splitting advantage while using `<ComponentOne />` approach.

Comment: Together with importing code that might not be used, code splitting advantages are lost.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but what do you mean by "this will impact on performance"? Bundler performance? It doesn't matter in my case cuz there is no sense to use `Sidebar.Link` without `Sidebar`

Comment: @streletss Performance I meant for that importing all but using some. In your case, there'll be no effect since you're using all imported component.

Answer (score 0):

The pros and cons of certain methods are subjective, in my opinion it is better to export both components because i don't think there is an overhead in doing so. Considering **component reuse**, or **code maintenance** if something were to change as well as the tendency to follow this approach for larger components,

> I wouldn't recommend this approach even for simple components.